# Sign to warn tourist about water

Tags: word-choice

We have to put up a sign for tourists: the concept is that the water hasn't been tested so you can drink but at your own risk. Which one is correct/better?

1. Water not controlled
2. Not (non?) controlled water
3. Untested water
4. Not (non?) tested water
5. Water not analyzed

Comment: Asking which is better/best, as opposed to simply ensuring that your usage is grammatical and carries the intended meaning, places this question into the realm of opinion, and risks having the question closed on that basis.

Comment: Reminder to answerers. Please **do not answer in comments.** Write a corroborated/justified answer where the question is on-topic. This helps the system keep track of questions which are actually unanswered. (And if a question is off-topic, vote to say so.)

Comment: I don't think ELU is the best place to get recommendations for wording for health concerns.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for ***untested water***. The term ***[water testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_testing)*** exists. [The Planet Magazine](https://theplanetmagazine.net/lead-in-the-water-dd73d6461082) has a post about it which says:

> Before you stoop for a drink at Western’s ***untested water*** fountains, ask yourself, is it really worth it?

It has this picture with a detailed notice, saying:

> Water testing results pending mitigation completion. Please use other sources for drinking until further notice.

[image]

If there is a risk, it is better to be explicit about it, rather than concise.

You could also say *water not tested*, though sometimes this expression requires a continuation (*for lead*, *by a laboratory*, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Only 2. and 4. are incorrect or unidiomatic.  ("Untested" or "uncontrolled" would be more correct.)

However I don't think any of the choices given are a good under these circumstances.

Vaguely describing the status of "control" or "testing" is far too indirect an approach for communicating a safety concern.  What would you be testing or controlling for anyway, temperature? pressure?  I know you're talking about pathogens or chemical contaminants, but I work for an engineering firm that builds water treatment plants.  I wouldn't expect that knowledge from the general public.

I would say: "Water may contain organisms that can cause disease." or "Water may contain arsenic which may cause poisoning." or something like that.  Then follow up with "Drink at your own risk."

Comment: I don't think the average English speaker would understand 'control' in the sense of 'test'. 'Not controlled' sounds as though it might suddenly drench you.